# Extend a figure 100% horizontally with a fixed height in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, typesetting

How can I insert a figure (i.e. graphic) that extends 100% of the viewport but with a given height?

Comment: i would suggest that this is a question for http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the usual [width=X,height=Y] parameters, but instead of giving a literal X use \columnwidth...

If you want the figure to span multiple columns, use \begin{figure*} instead of \begin{Figure}

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

`\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5in]{imagefile}`

but construction

`\begin{minipage}{8cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imagefile}
\end{minipage}`

will produce image with width of 8cm.